# how to get id of an object from url of page django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have created a list in which it shows the name of all groups present  when you click it redirect to another page with group id, when i create a post i need to specify which group it is, i am getting the id in url of page but i have no idea how to define group object with that url,

**views**

```
def create(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    name = request.user
    author = request.user
    message = request.POST['message']
    message = comments(user=author,message=message,name=name,group_id=2)
    message.save()
    return HttpResponse('')
```

**instead of group_id=2 or hardcode it , can i automatically take the id from url of the page like we do in request.user**

**models**

```
class group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.id} group'



class comments(models.Model):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group = models.ForeignKey(group,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user} comments'
```

**i have been trying day and night and couldnt solve, all the genius programmers out there pls give me a solution**

Answer (score 1):

`urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/<int:group_id>', views.create)
]
```

`views.py`

```py
def create(request, group_id):
if request.method == "POST":
    name = request.user
    author = request.user
    message = request.POST['message']
    message = comments(user=author,message=message,name=name,group_id=group_id)
    message.save()
    return HttpResponse('')
```

As an example if you are running your app on localhost going to `localhost:8000/create/1` will make `group_id` = 1, going to `localhost:8000/create/2` will make `group_id` = 2 etc..